# How to show Flatlist item separator component on bottom

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have some items in a flatList in which I have used itemSeparator component to show the divider between the list but by default flatList render divider in between items, and I need to show the divider to the bottom also, is that any way to do this.

Thanks in advance

I have tried with index but that is not working on the flatList item separator, and I do not want to customise item to show the bottom line of the item. so is it possible with item separator to show the bottom line.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your items to `CellRendererComponent`  https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#cellrenderercomponent and apply styling to it

Answer (score 0):

Try just put divider in renderItem function. With this you will have clear YourItem and Divider in any element you have, or you can try use Example #2.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({item}) => <><YourItem {...item} /><Divider/></>}    
        contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}
    />
</View>
```

Example #2

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderYourItem}
        ListFooterComponent={() => <><ItemSeparatorComponent/><CustomButton /></>}
        contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}} 
    />
</View>
```